# Cannot paste into input fields using Selenium Webdriver on IE

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, copy-paste

I am not able to paste text into fields in IE11. The C# code I am using is:

```
Clipboard.SetText(username);
inputUserName.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

This seems to be working fine for Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: try with Robot framework.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to paste using InputSimulator. Here is the sample code;

```
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using System.Windows.Forms;

getInputField().Click();
Clipboard.SetText("text");
InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_V);
```

This works just fine as long as you don't loose focus of the browser;
Here is a link with more examples:
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator

I would like to thank Infern0 for the suggestion.